# Code not identifying Swedish characters despite #include<clocale> in c++

Tags: c++, locale

I have to write a code in C++ that identifies and counts English and non-English characters in a string.

The user writes an input and the program must count user's letters and notify when it finds non-English letters.

My problem is that I get a question mark instead of the non-English letter!

At the beginning of the code I wrote:

```
...
#include <clocale>

int main() {

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");
...
```

(the locale is Swedish)

If I try to print out Swedish letters before the counting loops (as a test), it does work, so I guess the `clocale` is working fine.

But when I launch the counting loop below,

```
for (unsigned char c: rad) {
    if (c < 128) {
        if (isalpha(c) != 0)
            bokstaver++;
    }
    if (c >= 134 && c <= 165) {
        cout << "Your text contains a " << c << '\n';
        bokstaver++;
    }

}
```

my non-English letter is taken into account but not printed out with `cout`.

I used `unsigned char` since non-English letters are between ASCII `134 and 165`, so I really don't know what to do.

test with the word blå:
[image: test with the word blå]

Comment: Did you verify that your terminal supports utf-8?

Comment: UTF-8 is not ASCII; it’s a variable-length encoding of Unicode.

Comment: @user2079303 yes it does, it prints out the word 'blå' once.

Comment: which platform are you on? Even if your `setlocale` is effective a single `char` will only contain ascii characters not utf-8 code sequences which need 2 characters for european non-ascii characters.

Comment: @AlanBirtles on mac and CLion.

Comment: In that case the `setlocale` is probably unnecessary and you just need to deal with the multi byte utf-8 characters

Answer (score 1):

> non-English letters are between ASCII 134 and 165

No, they aren't. Non english characters are not between any ASCII characters in UTF-8. Non ASCII characters consist of two or more code units (those individual code units themselves can represent some character in ASCII) . å for example consists of 0xC3 followed by 0xA5.

The C and C++ library functions which only accept a single char (such as `std::isalpha`) are not useful when using UTF-8 because that single char can only represent a single code unit.

Comment: Also, ASCII only exists from 0 to 127 inclusive. Anything outside that is not ASCII, but may be from an extended encoding, like iso-latin-1, UTF-8 and myriad others.